# Haskell naive duplicate filtering

Tags: haskell, lambda, pattern-matching, higher-order-functions

I do not understand a sample solution for the following problem: given a list of elements, remove the duplicates. Then count the unique digits of a number. No explicit recursion may be used for either problem.

My code:

```hs
removeDuplicates :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
removeDuplicates = foldr (\x ys -> x:(filter (x /=) ys)) [] 

differentDigits :: Int -> Int
differentDigits xs = length (removeDuplicates (show xs))
```

The solution I am trying to understand has a different definition for *differentDigits*, namely

```hs
differentDigits xs = foldr (\ _ x -> x + 1) 0 ( removeDuplicates ( filter (/= '_') ( show xs )))
```

Both approaches work, but I cannot grasp the sample solution. To break my question down into subquestions,

1. How does the first argument to filter work? I mean

> (/= '_')

2. How does the lambda for foldr work? In

> foldr (\ _ x -> x + 1)
>
> ```
>        ^
> ```

the variable x should still be the Char list? How does Haskell figure out that actually 0 should be incremented?

Comment: I would use `length` just like you did here.   No idea why they spelled it `foldr (\_ x -> x+1) 0`  (at the very least it should be `foldl'`!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `filter (/= '_')` is, I'm pretty sure, redundant. It filters out underscore characters, which shouldn't be present in the result of `show xs`, assuming `xs` is a number of some sort.
2. `foldr (\ _ x -> x + 1) 0` is equivalent to `length`. The way `foldr` works, it takes the second argument (which in your example is zero) as the starting point, then applies the first argument (in your example, lambda) to it over and over for every element of the input list. The element of the input list is passed into the lambda as first argument (denoted `_` in your example), and the running sum is passed as second argument (denoted `x`). Since the lambda just returns a "plus one" number on every pass, the result will be a number representing how many times the lambda was called - which is the length of the list.

Comment: For (1) I figure it's supposed to be `filter (/= '-')`, to account for negative numbers.

Comment: I. e., second argument of foldr == second argument of lambda; third argument of foldr == first argument of lambda?

Comment: In a sense, you could say that. If you consider "==" to mean "relates to"

Answer (score 0):

**First**, note that (2) is written in so called *point free style*, leaving out the third argument of foldr.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_programming#Functional_programming

Also, the underscore in `\_ x -> x + 1` is a wild card, that simply marks the place of a parameter but that does not give it a name (a wild card works as a nameless parameter).

**Second**, (2) is a really nothing else than a simple recursive function that folds to the right. foldr is a compact way to write such recursive functions (in your case `length`):

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a]
foldr f z []     = z 
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)
```

If we write

```
foldr f c ls
```

- ls is the list over which our recursive function should recur (a is the type of the elements).
- c is the result in the *base case* (when the recursive recursive function is applied on an empty list).
- f computes the result in the *general case* (when the recursive function is applied on a non-empty list). f takes two arguments:

  1. The head of the list and
  2. the result of the recursive call on the tail of the list.

So, given f and c, foldr will go through the list ls recursively.

**A first example**
The Wikipedia page about point free style gives the example of how we can compute the sum of all elements in a list using foldr:

Instead of writing

```
sum [] = 0
sum (x:xs) = x + sum xs
```

we can write

```
sum = foldr (+) 0
```

The operator section (+) is a 2-argument function that adds its arguments. The expression

```
sum [1,2,3,4]
```

is computed as

```
1 + (2 + (3 + (4)))
```

(hence "folding to the right").

**Example: Multiplying all elements.**

Instead of

```
prod [] = 1
prod (x:xs) = x * prod xs
```

we can write

```
prod = foldr (*) 1
```

**Example: Remove all occurrences of a value from a list.**

Instead of

```
remove _ [] = []
remove v (x:xs) = if x==v then remove v xs else x:remove v xs
```

we can write

```
remove v = foldr (\x r -> if x==v then r else x:r) []
```

**Your case, (2)**

We can now fully understand that

```
length = foldr (\ _ x -> x + 1) 0
```

in fact is the same as

```
length [] = 0
length (x:xs) = length xs + 1
```

that is, the length function.

Hope this recursive view on foldr helped you understand the code.

Comment: (2) isn't in point free style, and doesn't leave out the third argument of `foldr`. The third argument is `( removeDuplicates ( filter (/= '_') ( show xs )))`.

Comment: By (2) I meant the expression foldr (\ _ x -> x + 1), which is point free when we name it, but I see what you mean.